# map map vs map.map

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell and I thought that the functions `map map` and `map.map` are the same in Haskell. 
My terminal gives me two different types,

```
(map.map) :: (a -> b) ->  [[a]]  ->  [[b]]
```

and

```
(map map) :: [a -> b] -> [[a] -> [b]]
```

How are those functions different from eachother, in terms of syntax, and what does each one of them mean exactly?

Comment: Why do you expect these to be the same?

Comment: I expected both to represent (map(map))

Comment: `f . g` is the same as `\x -> f (g x)`, so the `map . map` is equivalent to `\x -> map (map x))`, note that there is an extra `x` here.

Comment: and how about (f g)?

Comment: `(map map)` is the same as `(map $ map)` -- and `(.)` (composition) and `($)` ("applied to") are very different operators, although often confused.

Comment: So both are (map(map)) baically? or how does the x in map.map change the function? sorry if i'm being ridiculoous but i really want to understand

Comment: @SavannahGemp: no, there is a difference between `map map` and `\x -> map (map x)` since the latter takes as parameter something that is applied to the inner map, whereas the former applies a parameter as "second parameter" the "outer" map.

Comment: @SavannahGemp `(f g)` or `(f $ g)` applies `f` to the function `g` itself, not to the *result* of the function `g`.

Comment: One is `map` applied to `map`; the other is `map` applied to the *result* of applying `map` to something else.

Comment: `map map` = `\ x -> (map map) x` while `map.map` = `\ x -> map (map x)`. the difference is in how the parentheses are placed.

Answer (score 8):

The `map map` expression will take second `map` as the parameter of the first one. So that means that if we derive the type, we see:

```
map :: (  a     ->      b     ) -> ([a] -> [b])
map :: (c -> d) -> ([c] -> [d])
-----------------------------------------------
a ~ (c -> d), b ~ [c] -> [d]
```

This thus means that `a` has the same type as `c -> d`, and `b` has the same type as `[c] -> [d]`. It thus means that the type of `map map` is:

```
map map :: [a] -> [b]
        :: [c -> d] -> [[c] -> [d]]
```

Here `map map` thus takes as parameter a list of functions of type `c -> d`, and it will generate a list of functions that performs a mapping with these functions.

It thus means that if you write:

```
(map map) [(+1), (*2), (-3)]
```

you retrieve something like:

```
[map (+1), map (*2), map (-3)]
```

---

That is not the case for `map . map`. This expression is equivalent to `(.) map map`. The [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) function takes two functions `f` and `g`, and combines these as `\x -> f (g x)`. The type thus means:

```
(.) :: (  b     ->      c     ) -> ((  a     ->      b     ) -> (a -> c))
map :: (d -> e) -> ([d] -> [e])
map ::                              (f -> g) -> ([f] -> [g])
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
b ~ d -> e ~ [f] -> [g], c ~ [d] -> [e], a ~ f -> g, d ~ f, e ~ g
```

The type of `(.) map map` is thus:

```
(.) map map :: a -> c
            :: (f -> g) -> ([d] -> [e])
            :: (f -> g) -> ([[f]] -> [[g]])
```

This function takes a single function of type `f -> g`, and will generate a function that takes a list of list of `f`s and it can map these to `g`s.

So `(map . map) (+1)` will generate a function such that for:

```
(map . map) (+1) [[1,4,2,5],[1,3,0,2]]
```

it will generate:

```
[[2,5,3,6], [2,4,1,3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
map . map ≡ (\x -> map (map x))
          ≡ (\x y -> map (map x) y)

map map   ≡ map (map)
          ≡ (\x -> map map x)
```

So, basically the `.` smuggles an extra variable into the “function bracket” of the outer `map`.

It turns `map (map) x` into `map (map x)`. Both mean something quite different, as the types demonstrate.

In `map (map x) y`, the `x` is a function that'll be applied to the inner elements of the nested list `y`, because `map x` (partial application) is a list-mapping function. Whereas in `map map x`, the *higher-order function* `map` itself is mapped over the list. That sounds strange but it is possible, it just requires a list of functions (which will be the functions that the inner `map` maps) and spits out another list of functions (each of which does the mapping over one particular inner list).